# getting Permission denied(publickey) error upon git clone into VPS using ssh

Tags: git, ssh, digital-ocean, vps

I have copied the public key from my local machine into the authorized_keys file into my user's ssh directory on the VPS.
But when I do git clone I get and Permission denied(publickey) error

I get this log when I run

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 

debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2                     
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0 
debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0 
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git' 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org 
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none            

debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY     

debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.     
debug1: Found key in /home/sam/.ssh/known_hosts:1 Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.255.112' to the list of known hosts. 
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent     
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey 
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/sam/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sam/.ssh/id_dsa debug1: Trying private key: /home/sam/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sam/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

I'm not sure what else I need to do. I also created authorized_keys2 with the publickey but still no luck.

Comment: I can clone via HTTP but not with SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the private key (e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `id_dsa`) to the VPS and then add the public key to your your [Github profile settings](https://github.com/settings/keys) to be able to authenticate and clone your repo via ssh.